# JQuery How to add table cell to a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to use jQuery to dynamically add cells to my table row.

HTML:

```
<table class="col-md-12" id="location-table">
    <tr id="location-row">
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" id="location-radio"  value="other" />
                Other location
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS/JQuery (I've tried both of these methods):

```
$('<td><label><input type="radio" id="location-radio" value="test" />Test</label></td>').appendTo('#location-row');

$('#location-row').append('<td><label><input type="radio" id="location-radio" value="test" />Test</label></td>');
```

All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Both of those methods seem to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5gqRN/. My guess is that you're trying to run the script before the DOM is ready (specifically your table hasn't been drawn yet). Make sure you are calling this code within `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thank you!  This was just my test code but it verifies that the problem lies within the function calling it.  Thanks again!

Comment: While this is all good stuff, you should really check out knockoutjs.com it is easily one of the best things I have invested time in for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work..

```
$('<td><label><input type="radio" id="location-radio" value="test" />Test</label></td>').appendTo('#location-row');

$('#location-row').append('<td><label><input type="radio" id="location-radio" value="test" />Test</label></td>');
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but both work in jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/d5AdX/

Are you loading jquery correctly?

Comment: Turns out I wasn't placing my test js in $(document).ready().  Thank you!  Must be a problem with the function I'm using to call it

Answer (score 0):

if you open the chrome dev console while on your site and submit a dollar sign($) it should tell you it's a function. if on the right it doesn't have a link to a js file with a line number(something like 'jquery.min.js:2') then jquery isn't loading on your page and you need to make sure your head script is right.

here's a link to the google cdn where you can find all the jquery scripts:
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery